# AngularJS ngRepeat update model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use `ng-repeat` to render a `html table`. My controller looks like so:

```
app.controller("fooCtrl", function($scope, WebSocket) {
  $scope.foo = [ ... ];

  WebSocket.start(function(data) {
    // this is a callback on websocket.onmessage
    // here is a for loop iterating through $scope.foo objects and updating them
  });
});
```

As you can see, I am updating the `$scope.foo` array periodically. However, my view is constructed like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in foo">
  ...
</tr>
```

The problem is, when I update `foo`, it doesn't re-render my table with new data.

How would I go about this problem?

Comment: Hi, do you perhaps know how to add an item to the top of a ng-repeat list? I can update my list - the new item is rendered, but it goes to the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Did you wrap the update in

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  // update goes here
});
```

? This should solve the problem.

Comment: Additionally, you can just put $scope.$apply() after the changes.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to call `$apply()` to force angular to do a digest cycle when you update the list, like:

```
 WebSocket.start(function(data) {
   $scope.$apply(function(){
      /* your stuff goes here*/
    });
  });
```

Comment: Gives me an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Scope> has no method 'apply'`

Comment: @JanNetherdrake please, see this article with description: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: @JanNetherdrake It's '$apply', not 'apply'.

Answer (score 0):

Following code work for me, Whenever you get message from socket you just need to bind your code inside $scope.$apply() function

```
 socket.on = function (e) {

            $scope.$apply(function () {
               // update you UI over here
            });

        };
```