# How to refresh table data after insert or update?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My table data is not updated after I insert a new record.

**Index view**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <table class="large-12">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Voornaam</th>
                    <th>Achternaam</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                    <td>{{employee.FirstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.LastName}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#/employee/{{employee.Id}}">Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Employee create view**

```
<form name="employeeForm" ng-submit="employeeForm.$valid && save(employee)">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <label>Voornaam:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="employee.FirstName" required/>

            <label>Achternaam:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="employee.LastName" required />

            <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" class="small button" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Employee resource**

```
angular.module("resources.employees", ["ngResource"])
.factory("Employees", ["$resource", function ($resource) {
    var Employees = $resource("http://localhost:9000/api/employee/:id", { id: "@id" }, {
        update: {
            method: "PUT",
            params: { id: "@id" }
        }
    });


    return Employees;
}]);
```

**Employees module**

```
angular.module("employees", ["resources.employees"])
.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/employee", {
        controller: "EmployeeListController",
        templateUrl: "/employee/index"
    })
    .when("/employee/create", {
        controller: "EditEmployeeController",
        templateUrl: "/employee/create",
        resolve: {
            employee: ["Employees", function (Employees) {
                return new Employees();
            }]
        }
    })
    .when("/employee/:id", {
        controller: "EditEmployeeController",
        templateUrl: "/employee/edit",
        resolve: {
            employee: ["$route", "Employees", function ($route, Employees) {
                return Employees.get({ id: $route.current.params.id });
            }]
        }
    });
}])
.controller("EmployeeListController", ["$scope", "$location", "Employees", function ($scope, $location, Employees) {
    $scope.employees = [];

        Employees.query(function (response) {
            $scope.employees = response;
        });
}])
.controller("EditEmployeeController", ["$scope", "$location", "$routeParams", "employee", function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, employee) {
    $scope.employee = employee;

    $scope.save = function (employee) {
        if (employee.Id === 0 || employee.Id == undefined) {
            employee.$save(function (response) {
                $location.path("/employee");
            });
        } else {
            employee.$update({ id: employee.Id }, function (response) {
                $location.path("/employee");
            });
        }
    };
    $scope.back = function () {
        $location.path("/employee");
    };
}]);
```

I'm new to angular js and i have tried almost everything to get the job done, but without any luck. Can somebody explain why my table only gets updated after hitting F5 and how I can fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: can you add console.log like here to double check if you get new data after you back to employee/index from add view Employees.query(function (response) { console.log(response);     $scope.employees = response; });

Comment: You should share the same scope between EmployeeListController and EditEmployeeController and simply do a $scope.employees.push($scope.employee) inside the save function

Comment: I will try to create a service that shares a reference to a data object that both controllers can use. This would be done by $q and defferd load right?

Comment: @sylwester it does not hit the webservice after I return to the index page.

Comment: @RobAngelier that really weird that controller using cashed data. please see that http://plnkr.co/edit/itsVeOl75F6tlYuizImf it is working for me try to update your EmployeeListController to that version

Answer (score 0):

Take at look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599877/angularjs-ngrepeat-update-model)

You need to $apply scope when it is updated.

Comment: That doesn't work also, i've tried to wrap my update inside a $scope.apply(function(){}); but this doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need to wrap you update into $apply. Execute $apply after  model is updated. If this will not help - I would rather copy response into model, eg.: $scope.employees = angular.copy(response); $scope.$apply();

Comment: its `$apply` not `apply` ... `$scope.$apply(function(){ //will update code here})`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after two days of trying. I created the following plunk that seems to work pretty well:

`plunk code`http://plnkr.co/fcyPLVJpwXJQgNb7CkSO

The problem occurs when I run the API on my local machine. The application started to work after I deployed my API to a test server.

I used a asp.net mvc 5 project in combination with a web api 1 project, just so you know.