# ngRepeat does not update the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

#### The Problem

I have a `ngMake()` function which makes a request to `makepost.php` and using the user's input it adds a new "post" to the database. This operation is successful, and I know this, because after I fill in the `makepost.html` form and I refresh the page, the newly created post is there. I want it so that the page needn't be refreshed. As I have gathered Angular's two-way data-binding should take care of this automatically, so maybe I have some problem with the `$scope`, I've been reading, but I guess because I am a beginner I don't really know what is causing the issue, or if I should create a new function which makes use of `$scope.$watch()`, I've sort-of tried `$scope.$apply()`. I don't know, anything would be helpful, thank you.

#### Factory 'postFactory'

```
app.factory('postFactory', function($http) {
var postFactory = {
    async: function() {
        var promise = $http.get('server/blog/posts.php')
            .success(function(response) {
                return response;
            })
            .error(function(error, status) {
                $scope.response.error = { message: error, status: status };
                console.log($scope.response.error.status);
            });
        return promise;
    }
};
return postFactory;
```

});

#### Inside the blog.controller

```
postFactory.async().then(function(response) {
    $scope.posts = response.data.Posts;
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="BlogController as blog">
<div class="dont-break-out" ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <a href="#{{post.Slug}}">
        <hr>
        <h4>{{post.Title}}</h4>
        <div ng-bind-html="ngHTML((post.Content | limitTo : 125) + '..')"></div>
    </a>
    <footer class="text-right"> On {{post.DateSubmited}}
        <br> By {{post.UserName}}
    </footer>
</div>
<hr>
```

#### The entire project on [GitHub](https://github.com/AquaSolid/RAMA_Angular_PHP)

Comment: Try adding `track by` into ng-repeat.. see docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: I tried `ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index"` but to no avail, it didn't work. it's weird, after I `makepost.php` I do a `console.log($scope.posts);` and the new post is added. I added three more posts and they were there too, so I decided to `ng-bind="$scope.posts.length"` on a regular `<p>`-tag, and that didn't update as well. I am getting really confused..

Comment: This is one of the reasons why i moved from angular to React js :) you should put some unique identifier from your post to that `track by` see the docs.. angular will render only if something has changed..

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20599944/2611927

Comment: @Hardy I mentioned in my opening paragraph that I "sort-of tried `$scope.$apply()`", I tried again after seeing your comment, and once more I get massive errors `[$rootScope:inprog] `. I don't know..

Comment: Do it: `npm install react react-dom` :) seriously, never been more happy that i did that..

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are returning the posts list inside a data property?. i read your code in posts.php and i do find an object that holds the list of posts, but it is returned just like that

```
echo json_encode(array(
        'Posts' => $rows
     ));
```

and in your js code you are requesting

```
$scope.posts = response.data.Posts;
```

maybe it is that you are confused about the kind of promise you are handling at that moment, when you use the $http method it does return a data property, but a normal promise doesn't do that, you access directly the data in your object like this:

```
$scope.posts = response.Posts;
```

Comment: I have all of the posts listed/displayed. `ngRepeat` works, it just needs a page-refresh to update itself, and that's the problem I am trying to figure out.. I think the PHP/back-end to be decent.

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-repeat isn't updating because it's always pointing at the original `posts` array, even when you've gotten a new one.

What happens is that on your initial page load, you get a brand new array (let's call it `array1`) from the server, and you give that array to both your `$scope` your ng-repeat.  When you make a new post and call `async()` a second time, you get back *another* brand new array (`array2`), and you give it to your `$scope`, but *not* ng-repeat.  It's already got its array; it's happy.  It doesn't know or care what `$scope` thinks the new array is--they can point to completely different lists.

This is a subtle problem you can see a lot with Angular views, and it's one of the reasons you will often see people recommend that you never reference anything in the view without accessing it as a property of something else.  That way, when you change the property on the container object, `ng-repeat` will see the change because it's watching the container object's property rather than just holding its own reference with no connection to anything else.

To solve your issue, you can create a new container object (let's call it `data`), and place the `posts` property on it instead.

So inside your blogController, you would start by declaring

```
$scope.data = {};
```

and then your calls to `async()` would look like

```
postFactory.async().then(function(response) {
    $scope.data.posts = response.data.Posts;
});
```

and your `ng-repeat` would look like

```
ng-repeat="post in data.posts"
```

The end result is that ng-repeat will hold onto the reference for `data` and never let it go, and it will automatically notice and update every time the `posts` property is changed.

---

As an aside, you don't need the $scope.apply() calls in any of your callback handlers.  Angular calls $scope.apply() at the completion of every $http request.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it didn't work. What you're saying does make a lot of sense. I have no idea why isn't it working..

Comment: I tried doing `ng-repeat="post in this.data.posts"` but that didn't work as well.

Comment: @AquaSolid Do you still have the call to `$scope.apply()` in your `success()` handler in ngMake()?  I didn't think about it last night, but attempting to call `apply()` or `digest()` during an existing digest cycle (such as handling a button click or the completion of an `$http` request) will cause Angular to throw an exception and not update the page.

Comment: I do not. If I had it none of the code gets executed, the entire controller stops working, plus I always check the console when running, so, I guess, I would know. Thank you for the help thus far. :)

Comment: Can you make a GitHub gist or something of your `blog.controller` with those changes?  Just want to make sure of what it looks like now.

Comment: I made a new commit, I'll need some time to figure out how to make a gist, lol. Feel free to explore the newly-made commit and once more, thanks. 
The file path: `RAMA_Angular_PHP/client/js/blog.controller.js`

Comment: Can the `$routeProvider` be doing this? Hey...I just tried with `$rootScope` and after another event, such as pressing a button it actually reloaded..wow, I just changed `$scope` to `$rootScope` specifically on `$rootScope.data = {};`..

Comment: I think your issue is that the `success` handler in `ngMake()` is still set to `$scope.posts = response.data.Posts;` instead of `$scope.data.posts = response.data.Posts;`

Comment: I removed that entire piece of code. Currently the `success` handler contains only one line `$location.path("/");` and it still works perfectly. So, that isn't the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the `then()` for `async()` inside `success()` in `ngMake()`.  In the gist (line 110) and your repo (line 107) it's still updating `$scope.posts` instead of `$scope.data.posts`, which would mean it's updating a different property than what the `ng-repeat` is using.

Comment: In the gist lines 109, 110 and 111 were removed. The code still executes. But, I guess, as I already mentioned,  I used `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` and now `ng-repeat` automatically updates itself, by the way, is there someway we can chat? Comments aren't really a place to have a conversation..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120368/discussion-between-angle-osaxon-and-aquasolid).